# Coded UI Tests Cross Browser Testing Design Patterns

Tags: testing, coded-ui-tests

Does anyone know a good book/blog/resource explaining design patterns for cross browser testing projects?

The MSDN link below explains how to set everything up.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx

This is all set up however we currently have a CUITs project with over 100 tests all setup and running on IE. And there were a lot of problems and required a lot of re-factoring of the UI Map, Playback settings, Test steps(as control aren't recognized) etc. to have even few tests  run smoothly. Plus since our clients always use the latest version of Chrome and Firefox the framework isn't up-to-date to support the newest versions. Hence, continuing the way we're doing right now it looks like we'll end up with bulky test code which will soon be nightmare to maintain as we add more tests to the project.

It would be good to know what are the best practices in terms of managing/isolating tests so it involves less re-factoring and smooth integration between tests for various browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) solution sounds like a perfect fit for your case. You can find

> best practices in terms of managing/isolating tests so it involves less re-factoring and smooth integration between tests for various browser

in these [test design considerations](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp). Take a closer look at the parts about  Page object model and Page factory for better understanding of

> design patterns for cross browser testing projects

If you eant to make a step forward with it, take a look at [selenium grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp). It allows you to run your tests on different machines against different browsers in parallel. That is, running multiple tests at the same time against different machines running different browsers and operating systems. Essentially, Selenium-Grid support distributed test execution. It also supports running your tests in a distributed test execution environment.

Comment: We're using microsoft's CUITs framework already and these are long complicated tests. Moving to Selenium would be the last option if there's no way we can sustain our current setup. Ideally we're looking for an existing tried/tested design pattern using CUITs framework for efficient maintenance.

Comment: I asked the question in 2014. It's 2016 and we've switched to selenium now. Although not the answer I needed then, it was the right advice.